# Clicking the button does not show the loader in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a loader to the button. That is, when you click on the Save button, you need to show the CircularProgressIndicator. I wanted to implement this through Bloc, because if I do this through setState (() {}), then I will have to rebuild the widget and the new added data on the page will disappear. Therefore, I want to do it through Bloc. I created a variable there and assign values ​​to it, the values ​​change but the loader does not update, tell me how can I make the loader show?

```
    return BlocBuilder<EditPhotoCubit, EditPhotoState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        child: _child(size, topPadding, context, cubitEditPhoto,
            mainState.charging),
      );
    });
  }
  return const SizedBox();
});
```

...

```
      SizedBox(
        width: 148,
        child: cubitEditPhoto.isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: constants.Colors.purpleMain)
            : DefaultButtonGlow(
                text: 'Save',
                color:Colors.purpleMain,
                shadowColor: Colors.purpleMain,
                textStyle: Styles.buttonTextStyle,
                onPressed: () async {
                  cubitEditPhoto.isLoading = true;
                  await cubitEditPhoto
                      .uploadImage(widget.chargingId)
                      .then((value) {
                    cubitEditPhoto.isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
      ),
```

**cubit**

```
class EditPhotoCubit extends Cubit<EditPhotoState> {
  EditPhotoCubit() : super(EditPhotoInitial());

  bool isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: You need to emit a new state on your cubit with the value isLoading. Something like "myFunction(bool isLoading){emit(EditPhotoState( isLoading);}

Comment: And then how to display this state in the UI so that the widget changes?

Comment: Your BlocBuilder will be triggered with the new state, you just need to use the value of this new state (state.isLoading).